# webservice dispatcher

Tags: c++, web-services, routes, dispatcher, middleware

Here is my problem: I have a C++ application that consists of Qt GUI and quite a lot of backend code. Currently it is linked into one executable and runs on Solaris. Now, I would like to run the GUI on Windows and leave the rest of the code running on Solaris (porting it will be a huge effort). The interface between GUI and backend is pretty clean and consists of one C++ abstract class (also uses some stl containers). This is the part I would like to turn into webservice.

The problem is that our backend code is not thread safe therefore I will need to run a separate process on Solaris for every GUI on Windows. However, for performance reasons I cannot start and finish process for every request from the GUI.

This design means that I need to take care of several problems:

- there must be a single point of contact for the GUI code,
- the communication must happen with the instance started during first call (it should either be routed or the first call should return address of the actual server instance),
- there must be some keep-alive messages sent between GUI and server process to manage lifetime of server process (server process cannot run forever).

Could you recommend a framework that would take care of these details (message routing/dispatching and lifetime management)?

Answer (score 1):

You could technically configure Apache httpd to spawn a new instance per connection.  The configuration also allows you to manage the time the processes stay alive when idle, and how many processes to leave running at a minimum.  This would work well as long as the web service is stateless.  A little weird, but technically feasible.

If you use something like gSoap, you can compile your C++ classes in Solaris directly into a gSoap mod and won't have to adapt it to any front-end like PHP or Java.  It'll just plug into Apache httpd and start working.

Edit:

I just thought about it, and you could probably use HTTP 1.1 keep-alives to manage the life of the process too.  Apache lets you configure how long it will allow the keep-alive to remain open, which keeps the thread/process for the connection active.

Comment: The service has to be stateful. Will apache be able to dispatch requests to appropriate process?

Comment: That may be a little trickier but I don't know a definite answer.  If these will be a part of a web farm, the obvious place to look would be something with a session stored in a shared storage location.  I'm sure it can be done, but I don't know what you can get out of the box.